# Symfony 1.4 : commands doesn't works and no message

Tags: php, ubuntu, doctrine, command, symfony-1.4

I try to create in symfony 1.4 the tutorial "jobeet" and I arrive at a place where I am blocked. I have to set up the db, I made one with:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p create jobeet
```

It works, the db is created and later I have to say to the project that jobeet uses this db with:

```
php symfony configure:database " mysql:host=localhost; dbname=jobeet " root mYsEcret
```

But when I type symfony's commands ,I never have messages of sucess or fail. Normally it should not work because the pwd is not "mYsEcret".
By the way, i tried to run other commands like

```
php symfony doctrine:build - all
```

Nothing either. No build sucess or build failed. I am really stuck since a moment.

Comment: What if you try `php symfony`, do you have something?

Comment: 1.4 is no longer supported I think, do you not wish to learn 2.x? However if you wish to learn Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine, there's a zipfile you can download with a working copy, day by day. See on the forum for that.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are running just configures the DSN, it doesn't try to connect so it will always work.

```
php symfony help configure:database 


Description:
 The configure:database task configures the database DSN
 for a project:
```

Check your error logs, also, can you connect to mysql from your cli using those details?

Comment: so i tried your command php symfony help configure:database:                                  leo@ubuntu:/var/www$ php symfony help configure:database 
leo@ubuntu:/var/www$

Comment: it did nothing and where can i find my error logs of terminal as you suggested ?

Comment: Can you run any symfony commands? what about just 'php symfony', that should list all commands to you, otherwise you have a problem with your setup and need to sort that out first.

Comment: with php sympfony i have nothing, no message, nothing more. What is wrong ?

Comment: Your app isn't setup right so nothing will wok. Go back to settin. Up the project, might be permissions or something's else.